# iOS : Immediately answering call from VOIP when app in kill mode, CXAnswerCallAction method doesn't call.(Using Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, cxprovider

I'm implementing video call functionality using WebRTC, Implemented VOIP with call kit. Everything working fine except below.

Step1 : App in kill mode
Step2 : Got the VOIP for incoming call
Step3 : within minor milliseconds tap on answer call button from VOIP(Right Icon)
Step4 : **func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {} this method doesn't call**

Only cause the issue for kill-mode, working fine for background & foreground mode.

[image]

I'm reporting the call immediately when **didReceiveIncomingPushWith** this method called, Also triggering the completion() within that method.

Already enabled relevant capabilities.

[image]

Expected to happen is, That method should be called so I can perform socket related task.

Comment: Have you got the solution to fix above issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have write `func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {}` methond in AppDelegate.swift, it respond immediately after tap on Answer button from voip even app in kill mode.

Can write CXProviderDelegate required delegate methods in AppDelegate.swift.

Previously I had written in my custom CallManager class and handling from there so it wasn't able respond immediately.